# Trying to display current time in div

Tags: javascript, php, html

divs timein and timeout are supposed to hold the values of current time when respective buttons are clicked. But onclicking they only flash and disappear

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head><title></title>
<script>
function inTime(){
 var time = document.getElementById("timein").innerHTML = 
 "<?php echo date('h:i:sa'); ?>";
 return time;
}

function outTime(){
var time = document.getElementById("timeout").innerHTML = 
"<?php echo date('h:i:sa'); ?>";
return time;
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="time.php">
<fieldset>
<legend>Time Log</legend>
<p>Time In: <div id="timein" value=""></div></p><br>
<button id="submitIn" name="submitIn" onclick = 
"inTime()">Time In</button>
<p>Time Out: <div id="timeout" value=""></div></p><br>
<button id="submitOut" name="submitOut" onclick = 
"outTime()">Time Out</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions can be simplified, and you can `return false;` on the button to prevent it from doing anything outside of the script you explicitly called.

**UPDATE** (further changes, based on use-case details from original poster):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="time.php">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Time Log</legend>
                <div>
                    <label labelfor="timeIn">Time In: </label>
                    <span id="timeIn" value=""></span>
                    <br />
                    <button id="timeInButton" onclick="getTime('timeIn');return false;">
                        Clock In
                    </button>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div>
                    <label labelfor="timeOut">Time Out: </label>
                    <span id="timeOut" value=""></span>
                    <br />
                    <button id="timeOutButton" onclick="getTime('timeOut');return false;">
                        Clock Out
                    </button>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getTime(element) {
                var currentDate = new Date();
                document.getElementById(element).innerHTML = currentDate.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/([\d]+:[\d]{2})(:[\d]{2})(.*)/, "$1$3");
            }
            getTime('timeIn');   
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: New problem, the time displayed for timein and timeout is the same

Comment: You are feeding them both the saem value.   If you further explain what your code is trying to accomplish-- "busimess requirements"-- I may be able to help you out.

Comment: timein is supposed to capture the present time. After an elapsed period of time, when i click on submitOut, timeout should hold the value of the time when the button was clicked

Answer (score 0):

You're probably submitting the form

```
<button id="submitIn" name="submitIn" onclick="inTime()">Time In</button>
```

Without a `type` declaration, your browser is assuming that the function of this button is to submit the form. So even though your JS even triggers, you're forcing the page to reload. Declaring them as buttons only should fix that

```
<button type="button" id="submitIn" name="submitIn" onclick="inTime()">Time In</button>
```